# Recommendation of a good source on Lyapunov theorem in dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, analyticity, vector-fields

As part of my research I wish to read a full proof of Lyapunov's classic theorem on dynamical systems that for an analytic planar vector field where all Lyapunov/focal values are zero, the local phase portrait is a center. I have not found anything matching this even after extensive search efforts so I turn to the community for salvation. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how easy to find these books, but all (even excessive) details can be found in one of the following books by Andronov et al:

1. Qualitative theory of second-order dynamic systems
2. Theory of Bifurcations of Dynamic Systems on a Plane

(I think this is the first one, but not 100% sure)

Comment: These two books were my first thought, but I still don't know whether they translated from Russian or not :) But it shoud be the first book for sure. I also suggest to take a look at Lefschetz's _Geomteric theory of differential equations_ .

Comment: @Evgeny They are translated. Some time ago I saw both of them in English.